# td border radius with MPDF56

Tags: css, pdf, html-table, mpdf, border-radius

I have problem with border-radius. For example:

```
<table style="border-collapse: separate; border-spacing: 2px;">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td style="border: 1px dotted black; border-radius: 5px;">Name</td>
            <td style="border: 1px dotted black; border-radius: 5px;">lastname</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="border: 1px dotted black; border-radius: 5px;">Name</td>
            <td style="border: 1px dotted black; border-radius: 5px;">lastname</td>
        </tr>
</tbody>
```

In the browser I get the result I need:
[image]

But when I give MPDF56 code to generate a PDF, `border-radius` is disappeared, help me understand it.

Comment: Are you talking about https://github.com/Sotmarket/mpdf ? That library was last updated 9 years ago, so I would not be surprised if it is simply outdated in its CSS feature support.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Border radius on tables is not supported. https://mpdf.github.io/css-stylesheets/supported-css.html

[image]